# Lisp Reverse "all" Function

Tags: recursion, dictionary, lisp, reverse

I want to write a function in lisp that reverses all elements from the list using map functions but I don't have any idea how to start this.. I think I have to use the built in reverse function somehow..
For example if I have the list (1 2 3 (4 5 6 (7 8 9))) I would get (((9 8 7) 6 5 4) 3 2 1)
or if I had the list(1 2 3 (4 5) (6 7)) I would get ((7 6) (5 4) 3 2 1) ..
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: From your comments below, it seems that you are describing a recursive problem, for which the simplest solution is a recursive function (that is, a function that calls itself). I have tagged the question with "recursion" for that reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick answer, not sure about efficiency/elegancy:

```
(defun reverse-deeply (list)
   (mapcar #'(lambda (li) 
               (cond
                ((consp li) (reverse-deeply li))
                (t li)))
           (reverse list)))
```

Comment: The key is the recursion. This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that works for me in Common-Lisp.

```
(defun reverse-list (list)
    (if (atom list)
        list ;; Not actually a list, return the atom
      (reverse (mapcar #'reverse-list list)))

;; Testing it out
(reverse-list '((1 2 3) (4 5 (3 6))))
```

Output:

```
(((6 3) 5 4) (3 2 1))
```

Mapcar is a function that takes another function as its first parameter and a list as its second parameter. It then calls that function on each element of the list. It returns a list of all of the answers. So after I use 'mapcar' to reverse all of the sublists, I call 'reverse' again to reverse the bigger list.

The function that it calls on each sublist is 'reverse-list'. This checks if the list is an atom. If it is, then it returns itself. If it's a list, then it calls mapcar again on each element in the list, then reverses the result.

Comment: This is not quite what I had in mind.. this function reverses the lists but the sublists order have to be reversed also..

Comment: If someone doesn't know how `mapcar` works, it may be confusing, since there are two ways to achieve the result: a) reverse the top-level container list; b) reverse member-lists :)

Comment: That better? Sorry, I must have misunderstood what you were asking for.

Comment: @SnailBoy `(reverse (mapcar #'reverse '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))))` isn't obvious?

Comment: This also reverses only 2 levels of the list .. I need it to reverse all elements of the list including sublists sublists of sublist .. sublists of sublists of sublist and so on ..

Comment: Okay, I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun reverse-list (list)
  (let ((result nil))
    (dolist (e list result)
      (push e result))))
```