# Reverse list in CLISP

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write my own function to reverse list in LISP. The problem is input

> (revert '(2 3 (4 5 (6))))

My code looks like this:

```
(defun revert (l)
  (if (null l)
    nil
    (append (revert (cdr l)) (list (car l)))))
```

It returns

> ((4 5 (6)) 3 2)

instead of this:

> (((6) 5 4) 3 2)

How can I fix it to work correctly?

Comment: relevant: [LISP: multi-level recursive reverse function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1422735/1281433), [Lisp Reverse “all” Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374158/lisp-reverse-all-function), [Understanding Deep Reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4102996/1281433)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to reverse sublists as well, you have to use `REVERT` on the `CAR` as well as `CDR`:

```
(defun revert (l)
  (if (null l)
      nil
      (append (revert (cdr l))
              (list (revert (car l))))))
```

This however requires you to handle the possibility that `L` might be an atom, which should be returned as is. Since `NIL` is also an atom you can just change the condition to check for `ATOM` instead of `NULL`.

```
(defun revert (list)
  (if (atom list)
      list
      (append (revert (cdr list))
              (list (revert (car list))))))

(revert '(2 3 (4 5 (6))))
;=> (((6) 5 4) 3 2)
```

In Common Lisp, it's preferred to use full words for names, so it's better to name `l` `list`. You could also name the function something like `tree-reverse`.